# Javascript innerHTML is loading slowly

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to avoid having to make my menu on 5 different pages every time I wanted to make a change. So I used Javascript to recreate the menu at runtime, so that I can just change that script to make the menu change on all pages at once (I know, genius right?).

But here is the thing; While the code works as intended, the menu seems to first load, when the rest of the page have loaded even though I call the function with `window.onload`. I don't really know why that is. My guess would be that innerHTML is slow, or I load the script at the wrong time.

I tried loading it at `<head>` but that didn't make much sense considering the DOM doesn't exist yet. So I moved it down to the header tag, which is where the menu code originally was so that it loads when that header does. But it's the exact same behaviour.

If I enter any of the other pages where the menu is written directly in HTML, it loads right away like the rest of the page. Any suggestions?

```
window.onload = function () {
    var header = document.getElementById("header");
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'inner';

    div.innerHTML =
        '<h1><a href="-omitted-" id="logo">Dynamic Realities</a></h1>' +
        '<nav id="nav"><ul>' +
        '<li><a href="-omitted-">Home</a></li>' +
        '<li><a href="-omitted-" target="_blank">Forum</a></li><li>' +
        '<a href="-omitted-">Media</a></li>' +
        '<li><a href="-omitted-">The Team</a></li>' +
        '<li><a href="-omitted-">Open Positions</a></li></ul></nav>';
    header.appendChild(div);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right. `window.onload` is going to fire *after* the rest of the DOM has been loaded.

If you're placing it in the header, where it belongs in the DOM, you can remove the `onload` event, and just do it right there. That should make it work better.

Comment: Ah yeah, that did the trick. Is this practice considered viable? I am new at JavaScript so I don't know.

Comment: It might be better to use a server-side include, but in lieu of that, this is good.